# Buttons of Equal Sizes below ListView in Android with Activity Indicator

Tags: android, listview, button

In Android, How can i have buttons below ListView of equal sizes. Also the buttons should show and indicator of an activity running :

Example : &imgdii=&imgrc=UZQjvC20IaJ_PM%3A%3BraF-YhtnnBxVuM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.handster.com%252Feditimg%252Fjob_search_android_device.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.handster.com%252Fproduct-review.php%253Fid%253D198%3B250%3B375">https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Bottom+Buttons+in+Android&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ETDyUd64I4mzrAfbrYHYAw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=799#facrc=*&imgdii=*&imgrc=UZQjvC20IaJ_PM%3A%3BraF-YhtnnBxVuM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.handster.com%252Feditimg%252Fjob_search_android_device.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.handster.com%252Fproduct-review.php%253Fid%253D198%3B250%3B375

I tried with TabActivity, but would not want to use it as it is now deprecated method after Android 4.0.

Below is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/rssfeed_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't even know how to edit this question. Please organize the mangled text above this quote: "I am certianly not looking for TabActivity as it is deprecated now". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/rssfeed_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="367dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

</ListView>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="2.5" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="2.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="2.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Armaan : Thanks, that was really useful, but i was not looking for activity status with progress bar. I am actually opening activity onClick of button so how can I color that particular button when that activity is open

Comment: it depends on how you want it. when activity is open give background color to related button and change when other activity is open. it is on you how you want it. but it just need background color change.

Comment: accept as answer and upvote it if its useful to you.

Comment: Yes but to accept answer, one small change is required, when i remove progress bar and add 2 more buttons it goes out of view. Can you modify your code with 4 buttons sticked together of equal sizes ?

Comment: edited the answer. so check it now.

Comment: don't mention that @user2568219

Answer (score 0):

create one footer layout:

**footer_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerCategory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
  >

   // create your two buttons and activity indicator here

</LinearLayout>
```

now add this footer layout in your `list view`.

```
View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
yourlistview.addFooterView(footerView);
```